# VeeValidate - Property or method "$validator" is not defined

Tags: vue.js, validation, vee-validate

I've imported necessary components

```
import { ValidationProvider, ValidationObserver } from 'vee-validate'
```

and I've registered them

```
 Vue.component('ValidationProvider', ValidationProvider)
 Vue.component('ValidationObserver', ValidationObserver)
```

but when I try to access the $validator I am getting this error.
Simple `console.log(this.$validator)` is not working.

This is the template

```
<template>
 <ValidationProvider
  v-slot="{ error, valid }"
  :rules="rules"
  name="$attrs.name"
 >
 <input v-model="enteredValue" v-bind="$attrs"/>
</ValidationProvider>
```

Answer (score 0):

The components API in vee-validate 2 and 3 are different from the old directive API that injects a `$validator` instance into your component. You cannot mix both APIs, it's either one or the other.

In other words, you cannot access the `$validator` anymore. Consult the [`v3` documentation](https://logaretm.github.io/vee-validate/) to learn more about the Provider/Observer API.